# SQL Server SSIS Script Component - generic function to capture CSV (comma-separated values) of the faulty row

Tags: ssis, etl

I'm trying to create something generic, which can be re-used in multiple ETL SSIS packages, whereby if the CSV data row fails to be written in the destination SQL database table, we would capture this and report back a row, which has failed.

The data flow looks something like this:

[image]

I have managed to achieve this by modifying the *BufferWrapper.cs* inside the Transformation Script Component, I created a new read-only property:

```
public class Input0Buffer: ScriptBuffer

{
    public Input0Buffer(PipelineBuffer Buffer, int[] BufferColumnIndexes, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
        : base(Buffer, BufferColumnIndexes, OutputMap)
    {
    }

    public string RowCsv
    {
        get
        {
            var csv = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < Buffer.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                csv.Append(this[i]).Append(",");
            }
            return csv.ToString();
        }
    }
...
```

I then use this property to populate an output column. This is all great, however, this *BufferWrapper.cs* file is auto-generated each time you edit the script and hence my code above gets deleted. I am therefore seeking an alternative solution.

Comment: Are you sure you are saving the script by pressing the OK button on the component and not just save button in the script window? It should not be deleted

Comment: Yes, I do OK and it actually works like I say. But next time you edit the script , my code disappears. It also says at the top of the file that it's auto-generated DO NOT EDIT.

Comment: Did you do any ssis version updates recently? Make sure that in your .dtproj file you are referencing the right (or it is consistent) target server version. <TargetServerVersion>SQLServer2012</TargetServerVersion> - what ever the version you have